# Why are my Docker ports not exposed properly?

Tags: docker

I am trying to link Python and Redis container

```
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --link=redis dockerapp:v0.3
6fe4b6a7914126d9436f6a517114e98fbd0dc8f5fa9a0c7d70673f89e08cb792
```

Output of running containers

```
docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
6fe4b6a79141        dockerapp:v0.3      "python app.py"          3 seconds ago       Exited (1) 2 seconds ago                        unruffled_mestorf
fb3f1364c9f9        dockerapp:v0.3      "python app.py"          11 minutes ago      Created                                         suspicious_mclean
2749b8453eb6        redis:3.2.0         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   16 minutes ago      Up 16 minutes               6379/tcp            redis
e5d9713c462a        add2d820aa27        "python app.py"          6 hours ago         Exited (137) 3 hours ago                        elastic_leavitt
ffcfb4cd0082        debian:jessie       "bash"                   28 hours ago        Exited (127) 28 hours ago                       thirsty_elion
4e8205831452        tomcat:8.0          "catalina.sh run"        30 hours ago        Exited (143) 27 hours ago                       objective_lichterman
49aab8cae20c        tomcat:8.0          "catalina.sh run"        31 hours ago        Exited (130) 30 hours ago                       objective_khayyam
```

If I go to browser on http://192.168.0.12:5000/

```
This site can’t be reached 
192.168.0.12 refused to connect.
```

My app.py

```
app = Flask(__name__)
default_key = '1'
cache = redis.Redis(host='redis', port=6379, db=0)
cache.set(default_key : 'one')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def mainpage():

    key = default_key
    if 'key' in request.form:
        key = request.form['key']

    if request.method == 'POST' and request.form['submit'] == 'save':
        cache.set(key,request.form['cache_value']) 

    cache_value = None;
    if cache.get(key):
        cache_value = cache.get(key).decode(utf-8)

    return render_template('index.html', key=key, cache_value=cache_value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Logs

```
  File "app.py", line 7
    cache.set(default_key : 'one')
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why?

Comment: The `ps` command seems to show that your Image isn't running, doesn't it? Exited (1) 2 seconds ago What does the log show?

Comment: Your container process exited.

Comment: Please provide the content of the dockerfile of `dockerapp` and the output of `docker logs 6fe4b6a79141`

Comment: I added logs,take a look.

Comment: I got it ,it shoul be default_key,one

Comment: port is not open because the python app crashes. It crashes because it should be `cache.set(default_key='one')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typo in the key assignment? This works:

```
>>> import redis
>>> default_key = '1'
>>> cache = redis.Redis()
>>> cache.set(default_key, 'one')
True
>>> cache.keys()
[b'1']
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the main container process of the python aplication is not working properly since it makes the container stop. Your docker run command is perfectly fine, plus it doesn't seem eny port colision case. In my opinion you may check the command:

```
python app.py
```

Check the main process of your app.py and be sure it will keep alive even if the database connection fails.